# Github upload composer project

Tags: php, composer-php

I made simple composer project, uploaded it to github, create release called 1.0.0. When I can test download it

```
The requested package sobriodev/collection could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Why?

https://github.com/sobriodev/collection

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit it to packagist too.